# Is it safe to Install Mint's update manager(MinUpdate) on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, update-manager

Do you think it is safe to install Mint's update manager(MinUpdate)?

It was in `ppa:ferramroberto/lffl` repository but it is removed now. Do you know where can I find and install it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you mean `Mint update`?

Comment: yes,exactly. it is update manager of Mint

Comment: Here you go `packages.linuxmint.com//pool/main/m/mintupdate/mintupdate_4.9.3.3_all.deb` I doubt it will just work though, you likely need Mint dependencies, you can add there main PPA if the deb does not work but I am not responsible for any issues you face after adding this PPA, use it on Ubuntu at your own risk `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ qiana main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint.list' && apt-get update` then you can try installing with `sudo apt-get install mintupdate`

Comment: I don't know why the link won't add in this comment, just copy paste the link and it will download the file.

Comment: MintUpdate is really nice. You can see details about each updating package and you can manage installed kernels in a GUI fashion. But it's not tested and officially approved for Ubuntu. Might get you into trouble, conflicting with Ubuntu's Update Manager.

Comment: yes exactly. it needs Mint's dependecies. I decided no risking installing it. See this video, this guy install it in Ubuntu : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wz6_7REgos

Comment: @ipselute So it is similar to Synaptic?

Comment: @edwinksl: Let's say MintUpdate is like a better version of Ubuntu's Update Manager. But it's nowhere close to Synaptic. Synaptic is for experts ONLY. Synaptic is like a nuclear bomb. Don't use it unless you absolutely need it. Don't mess with Synaptic because it will definitely mess with you and your linux. I used Synaptic once to uninstall a package, and it automatically uninstalled several other packages, rendering xfce inoperable and had to reinstall entire OS again.

Comment: To answer the edit, NO it is not safe, when you add that Mint repo, there is a chance next time you update the system, many packages could be replaced with the Mint version creating incomparability and breaking your system.